# Flutter how to make a variable private and initialize it with @required in constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I make the field private and annotate it with `@required` in a class?

For example this code gives me error:

```
class AuthenticationService {
  final Api _api;

  AuthenticationService({@required this._api}); // error in this line
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class AuthenticationService {
  final Api _api;

  AuthenticationService({@required Api api}) : _api = api;
}
```