# Why is recommended to use final variables in widget as public?

Tags: dart

The standard that I see in repos is

```
class A extends StatelessWidget {

  final String title;

...
```

What would be the reason to use

```
class A extends StatelessWidget {

  final String _title;

...
```

Answer (score 0):

On using public variable, you don't see error while assigning values to the named optional parameters like:

```
class AnyClass extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  AnyClass({this.title}); // no error
}
```

But if you use private variable, like:

```
class AnyClass extends StatelessWidget {
  final String _title;

  AnyClass({this._title}); // Error: named optional parameters can't start with an underscore
}
```

Reason for the error:

> Named/optional arguments with constructor shorthand leaks impl details, [see more](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/3642)

Comment: `AnyClass({String title}) : this._title = title; // no error`

Comment: @Eugene You are right, you can do that but you have to create a variable, I actually used this approach to answer a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57937076/6618622) couple of weeks ago.